# How to create Fields in Customer Address in magento 2.3 on Frontend and admin panel

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4

I don't have any idea how to do that.
Can any one help me with this

Comment: check this link - https://store.magenest.com/blog/add-custom-fields-customer-address-magento-2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setup schema and create an address attribute with the setup script.

You can refer the below code of `installData.php`

Also you can refer the https://store.magenest.com/blog/add-custom-fields-customer-address-magento-2/ blog this can help you to add this fields in the customer  edit address page.

```php
<?php
namespace VL\CustomerRegistrationAttirbute\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;
    /**
     * @var CustomerSetup
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;
    /**
     * @var SetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;


    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param SetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        SetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            'customer_address',
            'company_name',
            [
                'label' => 'Company Name',
                'input' => 'text',
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'source' => '',
                'required' => false,
                'position' => 150,
                'sort_order' => 150,
                'visible' => true,
                'system' => false,
                'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
                'is_searchable_in_grid' => true,
                'backend' => ''
            ]
        );


        $company_attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer_address', 'company_name');
        
        // more used_in_forms ['adminhtml_checkout','adminhtml_customer','adminhtml_customer_address','customer_account_edit','customer_address_edit','customer_register_address']
        $company_attribute->addData([
            'used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer'
            ]
        ]);
        
        $company_attribute->save();

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```